# $window.sqlitePlugin undefined on iOS using ng-cordova $cordovaSqlite plugin

Tags: ios, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I am attempting to use the $cordovaSqlite plugin.
I use the $window.sqlitePlugin version to open the database because it has the same API as WebSql in Chrome so I can debug there.

When I deploy to Android it works without issue, but on iOS $window.sqlitePlugin comes back as undefined.

This is NOT accessed at the start of my app, so I do not think it device ready issue. I am actually going several menus in before trying to access it.

Any ideas why this would be undefined and why I can't use this plugin on iOS?